# Visual Studio double execution just adding OpenCV directory

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

i noted that when i'm working with OpenCv and i run the debug it runs two times! Even if the code is just an empty main(). I configured VS in this way:

C/C++>>General>>Additional Include Directories: $(OPENCV_DIR)\Include

Linker>>General>> Additional library Directories: $(OPENCV_DIR)\x86\vc12\lib
Linker>>input>> Additional dependancies

```
opencv_calib3d249d.lib
opencv_contrib249d.lib
opencv_core249d.lib
opencv_features2d249d.lib
opencv_flann249d.lib
opencv_gpu249d.lib
opencv_highgui249d.lib
opencv_imgproc249d.lib
opencv_legacy249d.lib
opencv_ml249d.lib
opencv_nonfree249d.lib
opencv_objdetect249d.lib
opencv_ocl249d.lib
opencv_photo249d.lib
opencv_stitching249d.lib
opencv_superres249d.lib
opencv_ts249d.lib
opencv_video249d.lib
opencv_videostab249d.lib
```

then i've done the same in the release using the .lib files without 'd'. Just doing like that i've the double execution, also with the following minimal code (note that the code is all under comment):

```
//#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
//#include <iostream>

//#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
//using namespace cv;
//using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ///Mat M(10, 5, CV_16UC1, Scalar::all(0));;
/// cout << M;

}
```

Another clue: in a more complex code, i use waitKey(0) and when i run the debug it runs the first time... after few seconds it stops and runs the second time... I noted that in the first run i cannot stop using the toolbar of VS (the 'stop' squared red button or the 'pause' one) while in the second run i can stop it using the toolbar. I tried creating a simple "hello world" code WITHOUT the OpenCv configurations and it runs just one time. So that i think that there is something wrong in my configurations.

Comment: Lemme guess, you're using Avast Antivirus with deepscan enabled?  Turn deepscan off or whitelist the directory you're running the program from.

Comment: Guessed! thanks a lot... it was the cause